# How to get a substring between certain characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a string `com.test.edu.personal.SomeException: this is some error: test message`. I need to get the string as `SomeException: this is some error`.

I am having troubles with my code:

```
declare @col varchar(100)

set @col = 'com.test.edu.personal.SomeException: this is some error: test message'

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@col, 
              LEN(@col) - CHARINDEX(':', @col) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@col)),
              LEN(@col) - LEN(LEFT(@col, CHARINDEX ('.', @col))) - LEN(RIGHT(@col, LEN(@col) - CHARINDEX (':', @col))));
```

I am getting `nal.SomeException: this is some` - I am missing something here

Comment: What are the rules that define that particular substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @col varchar(100)
set @col = 'com.test.edu.personal.SomeException: this is some error: test message'

Select Substring(@col,Len((substring(@col,1,charindex(':',@col)))) - CharIndex(Reverse('.'), Reverse((substring(@col,1,charindex(':',@col)))))-len('.')+3 ,len(@col))
```

Returns

```
SomeException: this is some error: test message
```

Comment: Thank you, I need SomeException: also. I need to extract: "SomeException: this is some error"

Comment: I think I didn't ask properly. The string SomeException is variable and I can get different exceptions. I need to just go back from first : till last .

Comment: @Lokesh No worries, just update your question with a more robust sample and desired results.  This way we can avoid the guessing game.

Comment: @Lokesh I understand what you are looking for... just a moment

Comment: @Lokesh Updated